# Laravel throws Fatal error when including autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, web-deployment

My entrypoint. index.php

I have uploaded it with this directory structure

```
root -> public_html -> laravel [contains all folders except public]
                    -> public -> index.php
                              -> public files
```

I am trying to deploy my project, but keep running into a fatal error. Do not know where I am going wrong.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This is the error

```
Warning: require(/usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/../psy/psysh/src/functions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/../psy/psysh/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:55 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(38): composerRequire11021545d8de1bcd9cc99ffff97d671b('801c31d8ed748cf...', '/usr/www/users/...') #1 /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/autoload.php(12): ComposerAutoloaderInit11021545d8de1bcd9cc99ffff97d671b::getLoader() #2 /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/index.php(37): require('/usr/www/users/...') #3 {main} thrown in /usr/www/users/pdffoeddae/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55
```

Comment: Did you run the `composer install` command on the server after deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are new to laravel but can at least run proper commands in a shell. Before running your project, you need to run the command : "composer install" in your project directory. It is responsible for generating these autoload files. I will assume you tried that already since that is the first solution if you google this error. Possible reasons for it not being generated might be either network error, the command getting interrupted or sometimes the absence of a bootstrap folder in the project root directory (if you are using it, I can not tell).

The best solution for you would be to run the command "composer update" in your project root and see if the file is generated. If that does not work, run "composer dump-autoload". Update your question if you are facing issues with these.